# How to add multiple route filters in Laravel 4.2 while using role:permission pattern?

Tags: laravel

I am having issues with using multiple route filters in Laravel 4.2 while using the pattern role:permission. I've attached my code below.

This doesn't work at all. When I change roles, it always give one 403 unauthorized. I want both moderator and administrator to access this route.

Perhaps there's a way to tell Laravel, "if the logged in user is either an administrator **OR** a moderator, then let them access this route".

```
Route::get('engage', [

    'as'   => 'engage_path',
    'before' => 'role:administrator',
    'before' => 'role:moderator',
    'uses' => 'ManagementController@showEngagement'
]);
```

This is my role filter.

```
Route::filter('role', function($route, $request, $role)
{
    if (Auth::guest() or ! Auth::user()->hasRole($role))
    {
        return Response::make('Unauthorized', 403);
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you show us your `role` filter?

Comment: Sure, see the edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use some kind of delimiter, like a `;` to pass in multiple roles.

```
'before' => 'role:administrator;moderator'
```

And change the filter:

```
Route::filter('role', function($route, $request, $value)
{
    if(Auth::check()){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $roles = explode(';', $value);
        foreach($roles as $role){
            if($user->hasRole($role)){
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    return Response::make('Unauthorized', 403);
});
```

Comment: I am doing exactly something like this. (Just popped up in my head) We think alike :)

Comment: Good :) You could even make it nicer by letting the `hasRole` method accept an array of roles.

Comment: Note that I am using `-` as a delimiter. Laravel doesn't recognize `,` in this scenario.

Comment: Interesting... `;` should also work (did that before)